# Magento 2 - Set Tracking Info for Order via REST API without specifying items?

Tags: magento2, magento-1, shipping, rest-api, shipment-tracking

Is it possible to add in shipping and tracking information for an order using the Magento 2 REST API without putting in the item information. We always ship the entire order and based on our warehouse setup, it's very difficult to specify the items. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you Checked to use extension_attribute? Here is the official doc http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

Comment: did you find a solution to the problem? i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Magento 1.7 and 1.9, but at least with those it ships everything if the product array is empty `array()`. Might be worth trying with Magento 2.

```
$result = $client->salesOrderShipmentCreate($session, $order->getIncrementId(), array(), 'automatic send');
```

Comment: do you have a solution that works for magento 2 via Rest API? thanks

Answer (score 0):

> For **Magento 2 API** Shipment tracking you can use Shipment tracking
>   repository interface. A shipment is a delivery package that contains
>   products.

**Method** `POST` `/V1/shipment/track`

> Body data

```
{
  "orderId": int,
  "createdAt": "string",
  "entityId": 0,
  "parentId": 0,
  "updatedAt": "string",
  "weight": 0,
  "qty": 0,
  "description": "string",
  "extensionAttributes": {},
  "trackNumber": "string",
  "title": "string",
  "carrierCode": "string"
}
```

> To delete that specific tracking reference; Deletes a specified
>   shipment track by ID.

**Method** `DELETE` `/V1/shipment/track/{id}`